# caught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am deleting the customer entry using id .
so I have customers.js file in which I am retrieving all the customers. I have added delete function which is not deleting the entry. In console , it is saying

> caught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead
> got a value of `object` type.

Code

**Customers.js**

```
export default function Customers() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(async () => {
    await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/customers").then((res) => {
      setData(res.data);
      
    });
  }, []); // This function retrive all the customers
 
  const deleteDocument = async (_id) => {
    await axios.delete("http://localhost:5000/customers/"+_id);
    // After deleting the document, update the state to reflect the change
    setData(data.filter((doc) => doc._id !== _id));
  }; // This function deletes the document using id.
 
  return (
    <div>
   {data.map((item,index) => {
  return (
    <StyledTableRow key={item.name}>
      <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
        {index +1}
      </StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
        {item.name}
      </StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell align="right">{item.amount}</StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell align="right">
        <Link to={"/customers/" + item._id}>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
            Transfer
          </Button>
        </Link>
      </StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell align="right">
   <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={deleteDocument(item._id)} >
            Delete
          </Button>       
      </StyledTableCell>

    </StyledTableRow>
  );
})}
 
}
```

In ***routers***  modules

**userdata.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const transactions = require("../models/transactionSchema");
const router = express.Router();
const user = require("../models/userSchema");

router.delete('/customer/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  user.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

function deleteDocument(id) {
  axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/customer/${id}`)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    // handle success if needed
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    // handle error if needed
  });
}


router.get("/customers", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const User = await user.find();
    res.send(User);
     console.log(User)
     
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).json();
  }
});

router.get("/customers/:id", async (req, res) => {
   const data = await user.findById(req.params.id);
   if (data) {
    res.send(data);
     console.log(data);
  }
});
 module.exports = router;
```

Comment: shouldn't your onclick look like this instead? `onclick="deleteDocument(item._id)"`

Answer (score 0):

Make the onClick input as a callback method

Change:

```
onClick={deleteDocument(item._id)}
```

To:

```
onClick={() => deleteDocument(item._id)}
```

Comment: Nothing is happening

Comment: @rushi can you show me you’re button component?